Discount factor to calculate MTM of FX Forward
Forward Contract e.g. Buy GBP Sell DKK
Which discount factor should I use? GBP or DKK? Or both? Why? What's the rule?
How to calculate the discount factor in the case above but also in general? Should I use price of repo and depo instruments and then interpolate? Does it change from currency to currency? What's a good general framework?
In case of selling GBP and buying DKK?

Assuming your accounting is in USD, and you have two physical future cash flows: one in GBP, and another in DKK. You discount each ccy cash flow with the ccy risk-free rate plus the ccy-USD cross-currency basis. If it's a non-delivery forward than the small wrinkle is that you need to discount to the date when the currency exchange rate is observed, rather than the cash flow date.

Thanks Dimitri! In practical terms what instruments are best to use to get the risk-free rate and the cross currency basis? Would it be ok to use the depo and repo instruments for the risk-free rate and cross-currency swaps for the ccy- currency basis?I'm really struggling to find practical material about these things. Is it just me?
